# How can I upgrade a MEC in Xcom: Enemy Within on iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcom-enemy-within

I've built a MEC in Enemy Within, but I'm struggling to see how I can upgrade it. When I go to `Engineering > Build/Upgrade MEC` and then select a MEC on the left hand side of the screen, the area on the right of the screen seems to show an upgrade path. However, the two upgrades have small padlock icons and say "LOCKED", with "This tech upgrade requires further research" written below.

How can I do the research to unlock this upgrade? I've tried all sorts of things in the lab and the foundry, but have had no luck so far.

Comment: The MEC-2 Sentinel requires the UFO Power Source research. Have you researched it yet?

Comment: Yeah I must have, because I've got a couple of the New Fighter Craft deployed